# collapsing actionbar not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'd like to collaps the actionbar, as chrome does, but it's not working:

This is my activity_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.moover.moover.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textViewWebPage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/secondToolbarTextColor"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/secondToolbarTextColor"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

So basically I need to collaps the action bar. I added the collapsing layout but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Move your toolbar inside CollapsingToolbarLayout (it seems that you created a copy instead). So the view with id `toolbar2` should replace the view, which now has id `toolbar`.

Comment: i have two toolbars with different ids. The first one should be the collapsible one

Answer (score 0):

CollapsingToolbarLayout has to be inside CoordinatorLayout

Comment: I had CollapsingToolbarLayout. I updated my post accordingly

Answer (score 0):

As whole xml is not visible so assuming format is not followed. Try this format in the xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
           ...
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                 ...
             <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                  ...
             </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
       </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Adding a good [tutorial](http://www.mindgrub.com/blog/matt-stanford/implementing-collapsing-toolbar-android-material-design) for reference.

Comment: I added the whole source code to the post and its respecting this format

Comment: I don't see the Coordinator layout, you sure you have it all in the activity_main.xml? Added a tutorial example that I have used in past.

Comment: I updated the post again. I followed the tutorial but it's still not working

Comment: Did you add the beginning snippet as the post you have doesn't show <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Comment: I updated again with the xml version and encoding at the top

Comment: what is the behavior that you see, not sure if the toolbar2 is maskingthe other view and forcing it not to behave.